# php line break issue - function return in echo of while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, echo, break

My Problem ist that the two first function echos in the while loop break the line in the code, after this it goes fine.

Function:

```
function firstFunction($string) {
$search = array(' - ',' ','.');
$replace = array('-','-','-');
$string = strtolower(str_replace($search,$replace,$string));
return $string;
}
```

My while Loop:

```
... 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
echo '
<!-- '; echo firstFunction($row['name']).' -->
blabla '; echo secondFunction().' blabla
';
};
...
```

Effect in Source Code:

```
<!-- course-a
-->blabla secondFResult
blabla
<!-- course-b -->
blabla secondFresult blabla
<!-- course-c -->
blabla secondFresult blabla
```

I want it to go this way:

```
<!-- course-a -->
blabla secondFresult blabla
<!-- course-b -->
blabla secondFresult blabla
<!-- course-c -->
blabla secondFresult blabla
```

Comment: Are u sure that the first row's `$row['name']` doesn't contain `<br>` at its end?

Comment: no there is no <br> or any other breaks in the mysql table. the second function takes vars from another col without any line breaks

Comment: ohh kevin thx for your great hint haha.. i deleted the firs row in my table and voila it works!! i looked for hours to fix this and i was not being able to see the wood for trees! thx for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because the `name` key's value contains a line break appended to it in the database. Try fixing it either by re-entering the value or by filtering it in the `firstfunction()` function of yours.

Answer (score 1):

I saw you already got the problem fixed but i don't have the reputation to comment yet and wanted to throw this bit of info your way

with your current firstFunction if the data is `a - b. c`

you'll end up with something like  `a--b--c`

i would suggest you change it to

```
function firstFunction($string) {
    $string = preg_replace("/[-\s.]+/", "-", $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: and what would be the regex for deleting brackets? I want to change "Course A (6 Weeks)" into "course-a-6-weeks" ?

Comment: just add () inside the []
so you end up with
$string = preg_replace("/[-\s.()]+/", "-", $string);
a good place to learn and test regex is http://www.rubular.com/

note: for your current example you would only want to add "(" not ")" or you'll end up with a trailing "-"

Comment: yes, regex is really useful but unfortunately i don't have the time to learn it right now. But thx for the link. I inserted () but the effect is "course-a-6-weeks-". Is it possible to delete the last "-" with regex or have i to go with with if & substr?

Comment: Since you would want to replace it with a different character (or in this case, no character) than the rest of the results, you would have to either do a 2nd replace or trim the last character off
Easiest thing is a 2nd replace
$string = preg_replace("/-\Z/", "", $string);

Comment: yes you are right! i took a 2nd substr /[-]?$/ and replace the last "-" if there is one ;-) rubular.com is nice! Thanks for your help and a good evening from vienna ;-)